# Findind a triangle's area results in a error:'float' object is not callable

Tags: python, trigonometry, area

I am creating a test program to find the area of a 3d triangle like this one:
[this one](https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=SOQnSShc&id=544F1816C60AFC8975C2EBB613239E97DB945368&thid=OIP.SOQnSShco2EzJayaNeFAtAHaEK&mediaurl=http%3a%2f%2fi.ytimg.com%2fvi%2fqlO6db60lvY%2fmaxresdefault.jpg&exph=720&expw=1280&q=3d+triangle&simid=608023980578178663&selectedIndex=33&ajaxhist=0)
I am having a problem with the last line which I expect to be perfect but reaulted in a type Error.

I lastly found out that I only set 1 argument, and it takes 2.
I don't know how to use google because this is a specific problem.
The main function is this:

```
def triangle3d(width, height):
    triangle2d = width*height/2
    length = math.cos(random.randint(3, 5))
    triangle3d = triangle2d*length
    assert (width*height*length)/2 == triangle3d;
    return triangle3d(triangle3d, triangle3d-2)
print(triangle3d(2, 4))
```

I expected it to just print out one number, but it resulted in a error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Public/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(triangle3d(2, 4))
  File "C:/Users/Public/test.py", line 9, in triangle3d
    return triangle3d(triangle3d, triangle3d-2)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Thanks!

Comment: One of your local variables has the same name as your function.  So it masks the function, blocking any recursive calls.  But there are more problems than that.  If you didn't have a name conflict, you'd have infinite recursion. So you need to re-think what you're trying to do.

Comment: Do not use the same variable name as the function name (`triangle3d`). Why is there the same name? Does it have a specific purpose? If not, it's a serious mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your function you assign

```
triangle3d = triangle2d*length
```

only to try to  call it later on (this is where the error is raised)

```
return triangle3d(triangle3d, triangle3d-2)
```

but if you just rename the local variable you will run into a `RecrusionError`...

your `length` can be negative. is that what you expect?